# Converting from 16 Bit Floating Point Binary to Decimal

Tags: binary, floating-point

I'm trying to convert a 16 bit floating point binary into a decimal number.

My binary number is 0010000101111100

Separation: 0|01000|0101111100

Sign: 0

Exponent: 01000 is 8 in Decimal

Mantissa:

Looking for an explanation on how I can use the Exponent and Mantissa to work backwards and find my decimal number. Thanks.

Comment: I found a post about this in stack overflow, maybe that can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404675/how-do-i-convert-from-a-decimal-number-to-ieee-754-single-precision-floating-poi

Comment: There are many variations on floating-point formats used in computers (which appears to be what your question is about). You should have received a precise definition of your particular floating-point format, which you should specify here. Presumably you have also seen examples of the evaluation of floating-point numbers from which you can at least make a reasonable guess how to answer this question. Show us. Even if you make a mistake, your work will be the best clue as to what kind of answer you need.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/OQsgrsl.png This is what I've managed so far but I presume it's wrong. I've also used this link to try and help me understand the method: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128204/how-to-convert-from-floating-point-binary-to-decimal-in-half-precision16-bits